# got Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' error while running jest if react is older version

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am having a project which is using react 16.X and with es6 and I added babel config
something like this
`module.exports = { presets: [ '@babel/preset-env', ['@babel/preset-react', {runtime: 'automatic'}], ], };`

But I am getting 'react/jsx-runtime'  error on running jest